# Java Lambda create bucket using the AWS SDK for Java V2 results in java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PROFILE_FILE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().region(region).build();
        String bucket = "new-bucket1234587723";
        CreateBucketRequest createBucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest
                .builder()
                .bucket(bucket)
                .createBucketConfiguration(CreateBucketConfiguration.builder()
                        .locationConstraint(region.id())
                        .build())
                .build();
        s3Client.createBucket(createBucketRequest);
```

While uploading lambda i ensured the service role has s3,apigateway and lambda execution permissions.

I tried to debug, seems breaking at S3Client creation,any help ?

Answer (score 0):

This AWS Tutorial creates a S3Client object (and uses other AWS Service clients too) and makes successful calls within an AWS Lambda function.  Check the code in this tutorial and compare that to your code:

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

Answer (score 0):

If the client initilization is breaking then it could be due to incompatible libraries or HTTP client issues. Maybe try this.

```
//Maven config
<dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>apache-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.31</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.31</version>
</dependency>
```

Then this in your code:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
...

// Instance variables
private static S3Client s3;
Region region = Region.XX_XXXX_X;

...

// In the method 
SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();

s3 = S3Client.builder()
             .region(this.region)
             .httpClient(httpClient)
             .build();
```